# Casting classes in generic methods in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, mef

I have some classes and interface:

```
interface IAnimal { }
interface ILiveInZoo { }
class Cat : IAnimal, ILiveInZoo { }
```

Also, I have some methods and generic methods:

```
class Context
{
    private static CompositionContainer Container = null;

    public ILiveInZoo GetWhoLivesInZoo(string name)
    {
        if (name == "Cat")
            return new Cat();
        return null;
    }

    public void GiveFood<T>(T animal) where T : IAnimal
    {
        var methods = Container.GetExports<Action<T, EventArgs>, AttributeMetadata>();
        //execute methods
    }
}
```

And here is a use case:

```
Context context = new Context();
var cat = context.GetWhoLivesInZoo("Cat");
if (cat is IAnimal animal)
{
   context.GiveFood(animal);
}
```

As you can see in `GiveFood` metod I'm using `MEF`. In use case when I cast `cat` to `IAnimal`, in `GiveFood` method `typeof(T)` will be `IAnimal` not `Cat`. First question is:
Instance of `cat` variable is `Cat` class. Why when I cast it, `typeof(T)` will be `IAnimal`? 
My problem is when I cast `cat` to `IAnimal` interface, in `GiveFood` method, `GetExports` method returns method related to `IAnimal` not to `Cat` class. I found solution to fix that issue, it is using reflection:

```
Context context = new Context();
var cat = context.GetWhoLivesInZoo("Cat");
if (cat is IAnimal animal)
{
   MethodInfo method = typeof(Context).GetMethod(nameof(Context.GiveFood));
   MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(animal.GetType());
   generic.Invoke(context, new object[] { animal });
}
```

Now `typeof(T)` is `Cat` class and in `GiveFood` I can get methods related to `Cat` class. Is there another way (without using reflection) to solve this issue?

Comment: When calling `GiveFood<T>(T animal)`, `T` is the type of whatever you call it with. If called with `IAnimal animal; GiveFood(animal)`, `T` will be `IAnimal`. You could apply the visitor pattern here, but I'm not sure if its feasible here (I don't know if `Cat` and `IAnimal` is one of your classes, and whether there are a lot of other `IAnimals` or not).

Comment: There is an overload of CompositionContainer that takes Type instead of <T>. It's still reflection, but at the correct place in your code.

Comment: I dont really get your question to be honest & it could because of (little) understranding of MEF. Can the problem be simplified without mef .
Nevertheless, I do see a design flaw.  `ILiveInZoo` should inherit from IAnimal. Cat should inherit from `ILiveInZoo`. This should simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and easy to use Solution could be to use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic):

```cs
Context context = new Context();
var cat = context.GetWhoLivesInZoo("Cat");
if (cat is IAnimal animal)
{
    context.GiveFood((dynamic)animal);
}
```

Do note however that `dynamic` uses Reflection internally (with caching to make it a little more performant). So if you really want to avoid Reflection, the Visitor Pattern described in the other answer is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method on anything that implements `IAnimal` but want the actual type of the object to be used as generic parameter to the method `GiveFood`, the reflection approach is probably the least intrusive.

A type-safe but more elaborate approach that you might want to look at is the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (aka double dispatch, see code below). This would be particularly appropriate if you want your `GiveFood` method to have a different implementation for some particular concrete type implementation of `IAnimal`.

---

This involves defining a new interface,

```
public interface IAnimalFeeder // the visitor
{
    void GiveFood(IAnimal animal); // main entry point

    // The generic implementation:

    void GiveFood<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal) where TAnimal : IAnimal;

    // + some specific implementations (if needed)

    void GiveFood(Cat cat);
    void GiveFood(Dog dog);
    void GiveFood(Fish fish);
    void GiveFood(Mouse mouse);
}

public class AnimalFeeder : IAnimalFeeder
{
    public void GiveFood(IAnimal animal)
    {
        animal.Accept(this);
    }

    public void GiveFood<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal) where TAnimal : IAnimal
    {
        // here the type parameter TAnimal will be the actual implementation

        // generic implementation
    }

    public void GiveFood(Cat cat)
    {
        // specific implementation
    }

    // etc...
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    void Accept(IAnimalFeeder feeder);
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void Accept(IAnimalFeeder feeder)   // same code for each implementation of IAnimal
    {
        feeder.GiveFood(this);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The way you solve this generically is by including enough operations *in the interface you're exposing* to implement that method.

So whatever your zookeeper needs to know in order to feed an animal, whether that be their weight, whether they're a vegetarian, carnivore, omnivore, how many times per day they need to be fed, or whatever else you need to know about them.  That information all needs to be on your `IAnimal` interface, and each animal needs to provide an implementation of that information.